# Alternative to 1000s of if-then-else statements

Tags: java, android, if-statement, switch-statement

I am programming a Text based RPG game for Android in order to familiarize myself with Java and XML. I want to display a string array of choices across a ListView of buttons, and depending on which button the user presses, I want to update the activity accordingly with a new set of choices.

For example, lets say the game starts off with the following choices:

```
{option1, option2, option3, option4}
```

If the user clicks on option2 i want to display:

```
{2-option1, 2-option2, 2-option3, 2-option4}
```

or lets say the user clicked on 4 instead of 2. Then:

```
{4-option1, 4-option2, 4-option3, 4-option4}
```

So, i am trying to determine a speed efficient / memory efficient way of determining the next `String[]` to display.

Originally i was thinking about constructing a GIANT if-then-else tree (or switch statement - doesn't matter), where there would be an if statement for each possible option.
For example:

//`choice` is the user selected option

```
if(choice==option1){
   return {"1-option1", "1-option2", "1-option3"}
}else if(choice== 1-option1 ){
   return {"1-1-option1","1-1-option2","1-1-option3"}
```

And the List would go on and on until every possible choice returns a String[] that corresponds to the next group of options that are to be displayed.

Then, i started thinking maybe it would be cleaner and easier to do this with objects:

```
   MyObject newObject = MyObject(choice)
   newObject.getOptions()
```

where `choice` is a constructor parameter that initializes a `String[]` to the proper next set of options; and getOptions() returns this `String[]`

However, this is going to be a lot of objects, and i am not sure it will simplify things over the if/switch statement method.

So, any ideas of an efficient way to handle something like this?

Comment: Ugly, brittle, unmaintainable.  You should worry about those before you think about efficiency.

Comment: I agree, that is why i want to go about solving this "puzzle" with a proper structure, and i figure the if/switch statement method or object method that i proposed are not sufficient.

Comment: Does it have more than 2 levels? It could be defined in XML and unmarshalled into a hierarchical set of option set objects.

Comment: Personally, I find it hard to discern what you really need to do from this example.  The buttons and string arrays example isn't doing it for me.

Comment: duffymo, this is the general flow that i want: A user is given a list of choices, the user selects a choice, and based on that choice a new set of choices is displayed

Comment: Sounds like a tree or graph. Every choice is a state, and selection is an event that transitions to a new state. An XML or JSON configured state machine would be my choice.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (probably a HashMap) internal to your object to associate `"option2"` with `{"2-option1", "2-option2", "2-option3", "2-option4"}`.

Data-structure choice is very important in programming.

Comment: what he's returning is an array.. so you need to keep a array in value side of hashmap.. can't use {"abcd", "aa", "bb"} directly

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need a singleton object like **OptionProvider** with methods like :

```
 - List<Option> getFirstOptions() 
 - List<Option> getNextOptions(Option option)
```

This object can hold the information as to which options come after which option in a Map like `Map<Option,List<Option>>`. You can fill the Map manually or it could be filled with data from an XML file or a database.

Then you can have an utility class like **DisplayOptionUtils** with a method like :

```
 - String getOptionPrompt(List<Option> chosenOptions, List<Option> nextAvailableOptions)
```

That will return the way you want your options to appear to the user (it can for example use a StringBuilder to create what you need).

Then in your main class you can have something like that :

```
List<Option> chosenOptions = new ArrayList<>();
List<Option> nextOptions = OptionProvider.getInstance().getFirstOptions();
while(!nextOptions.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println(DisplayOptionUtils.getOptionPrompt(chosenOptions, nextOptions);
  Option selectedOption = Option.getByValue(getUserInput());
  chosenOptions.add(selectedOption);
  nextOptions = OptionProvider.getInstance().getNextOptions(selectedOption);
}
```

This design is not perfect (I come up with it in 10 minutes) but hopefully it will give you in idea on how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Transform the concept into a more general one: There is always a current state, and there may be a set of options for that state. Choices can then be understood simply as triggering state transitions.

So you could simply model that in XML as:

```
<state name="Main Menu">
   <option name="Buy" newState="Shop"/>
</state>
<state name="Shop>
   <option name="Exit" newState="Main Menu"/>
</state>
```

State and Option can be easily modeled as classes. There is no need for complicated code, just put all existing states into a Map. For changing state, just ask the map for the state that belong to that state name and set that state as the current state...